# Can javascript "show" a field's input value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field that shows a value 4 in the UI. The site is built using a complex build process that I do not totally understand (I work as part of a team).

[image]

When I inspect the HTML for the field, I don't see the value 4. [image]

I am confused about how this might happen. Is it possible that javascript is "showing" the value of the input field?

Comment: you might need to close and open the dev tools because they might be injected via scripts.

Comment: What are you confused about? You put a 4 in the input....

Comment: For the initial hit when the DOM loads and the value is not present the Chrome Dev tools will *NOT* show the value of an input field.

Comment: JS can do that, and [a lot more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM elements have *attributes* and *properties*. The two are not always identical. The web inspector, in general, shows attributes as part of the DOM structure, like.

```
<input type="text" value="4" />
```

However, if there is no `value` attribute, this does not mean that the element has no value. For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

When you load the page, the *attribute* `document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("value")` is `null`, and the *property* `document.getElementById("test").value` is `""` (empty string). When you enter 4 into the input field, the *attribute* "value" is still `null`, but the *property* value has changed to `"4"`.

Long story short, the web inspector is not obligated to show the value of an input since it is does not always appear in the DOM as an attribute.

Comment: +1, the short answer is that browser inspectors show whatever they like, in this case it seems to be showing the source HTML, not the state of the current DOM. There is no need for the *faux* XHTML markup, no one uses XHTML on the web (not even the inspector in the OP).

Comment: @RobG, not quite. The Chrome web inspector **does** show the state of the current DOM. If I actually go and set the attribute "value" on the input, it will reflect in the inspector. Additionally, I can create completely new DOM nodes and they will also show up. However, manually editing the input value on the page does not change the "value" attribute in any way, so the inspector does not reflect that part.

Comment: —yes, I didn't put that very well. The [*value* attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#attr-input-value) sets and reflects the default value, which may or may not be the current value (i.e. the value of the *value* property). So in this particular case, changing the value property either through the UI or script should neither add the attribute if it's missing nor modify it if exists. I'm surprised that separate attributes for default value and current value have not been added to HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can change the value in javascript. and that is what is happening in your case

```
document.getElementById("materials_price_1").value = "4";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is.

If the input contains a `4` that does not mean the attribute `value` will be equal to 4.

It just means that the **value** of the input is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just check value of this field with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('materials_price_1').value;
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('#materials_price_1').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you using chrome you can in inspect element stand with the mouse on the elemnet in 'Elements' tab and right click.

Now choose 'Inspect DOM Properties' this will open you bottom of the tab the console tab. there you can find the DOM object of your field. open the object and find property value. this is the active value right now

Answer (score 0):

Sure. it happens in the DOM. you can simply make it blank by writing this code in your body tag :

```
<script>
document.getElementById('materials_price_1').value='';
</script>
```

just make sure you put the code after your other Javascript codes.